# Simple learning app with Rails 4 - Course / Enrolment / User Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to build a simple learning app with rails 4.

here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :lectures, through: :enrollments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments
end


class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :lecture
end

class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrollments 
    has_many :users, through: :enrollments
end
```

And here are my controllers

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def create 
        @enrollments = current_user.enrollments.build(enrollment_params)
        if @enrollments.save 
            flash[:success] = "You have successfully enrolled."
            redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
        else 
            flash[:danger] = "Please try again."
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    private

        def enrollment_params 
            params.require(:enrollment).permit(:user_id, :lecture_id)
        end


end
```

Here are my views:

lectures/index.html.erb

```
 <% @lectures.each do |lecture| %>
            <%= image_tag lecture.picture.url(:medium) %>
            <p><%= truncate(lecture.description, length: 80) %> </p>
            <%= link_to "Enroll Now", {:action=>"create", :controller=>"enrollments"},  :method => :post %>
      <% end %>
```

The problem is that when you click on Enroll Now I have the following error:

**ActionController::ParameterMissing in EnrollmentsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: enrollment**

```
def enrollment_params 
            params.require(:enrollment).permit(:user_id, :lecture_id)
        end
```

**How can i make it work? Need help please**

Comment: Please post the code of your from, from where you are sending the data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `lectures/index.html.erb` file, you are not passing any data to the controller's action method.

```
<%= link_to "Enroll Now", {:action=>"create", :controller=>"enrollments"},  :method => :post %>
```

Might be better served with something a la

```
<%= link_to "Enroll Now", {:action=>"create", :controller=>"enrollments", :user_id => current_user.id**, :lecture_id => lecture.id},  :method => :post %>
# ** not sure how you snag the current user's id in your app but you'd need it.
```

Also, take a look at [Routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). There are some super handy helper methods you can use that will allow you to do something like this (this was done quickly and may not be totally accurate but is offered to show you how you can use a route's path helper to clean up the code and make it even more readable):

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll Now', enrollments_path({enrollment: { user_id: current_user.id, lecture_id: lecture.id }}), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: hey Craig, I tried with your code and I am still getting the error. Any idea? Cheers

Comment: Adrien, which one of those snippets did you try :)? And, it's the same error, yes?

Comment: tried that one <%= link_to "Enroll Now", {:action=>"create", :controller=>"enrollments", :user_id => current_user.id**, :lecture_id => lecture.id},  :method => :post %>. Yes still the same error, and i am using the current_user method so it should be fine. Don't understand why

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting back so quick. Try the other one with the `enrollments_path(xxxxx)` ... the first one is probably just off, syntax-wise, as I don't use that approach personally!

Comment: Still the same error. Do you think there is another way of doing the same manipulation?

Comment: There are but that second approach should be sending it correctly, which is odd that it's erring. Wait ... dammit! Going to update my answer. Forgot about strong params.

Comment: Notice how I, like a dummy, forgot that your EnrollmentsController is looking for params as part of an enrollment hash (`params.require(:enrollment)`) ... I believe we just needed to make that explicit in the `enrollment_paths()` call)

Comment: can't figure out what you said, it drove me crazy for the whole day.

Comment: How would it be ? Sorry to spam you

Comment: Not at all. I'm running errands on my lunch break and will check more when I get home!

Comment: I'm afraid not ... was offline all weekend. I tried a few things in a console and via a web interface and the corrected format above `(enrollments_path({enrollment: { etc: 'val' }})` works for me locally to send in the required params).

Comment: Hey I got it working ....     <%= link_to 'Enroll Now', enrollments_path(@enrollment, enrollment: {user_id: 'current_user.id', lecture_id: lecture.id}), :method => :post %> that made it work I have no idea why but test turned green

Comment: Thank you for your help :) love the rails community

Comment: Glad it's working :). And the Rails community really does rock!